# I am trying to make regex but failed in matching

Tags: regex

**Random Text**

```
 qty 2 MBC102 Rs. 1,890 
required 2unit MBC 103 
mbc 104 2pcs @5000 
MBC 1011 @4000 4 pc Price 5000 
3pcs MBC1012 100rolls 
MBC1013 500 pc 
MBC1014 2pcs mbc 1015 
qty 2 @ 20000 unit 2 
@900 MbC-1016 rolls 150 
5000Rs mbc909 mbC 890 
56 qty @ 5000 
mbC 820 qty 90 @25000
```

**Want to match quantity**

```
2
2
2 
4 
3 
100 
500 
2 
2 
150 
56 
90
```

**I tried this code but not work properly**

```
(?i)^(?!qty|unit|pc|pcs|roll|rolls).[0-9]+
```

Comment: `qty` is before the number, `unit` and `pcs` are after the number. You can't use the same regexp for both cases.

Comment: Is there any logic to it, like for qty? Also 24 is not present right?

Comment: Sorry i make a mistake is 4 not 24

Comment: @Barmar can you please guide 2 codes for matching 1 is before and 1 is after

Comment: Is there really a space before `qty` on the first line? Or is `qty` always the first word on the line with no spaces before it?

Comment: @Barmar no space is okay

Comment: Why should this match 56 in `56 qty` but match 90 in `820 qty 90` and it the match 2 for `2unit` or for `2pcs`?

Comment: ... and how are you getting `4` from  `mbc 104 2pcs @5000` ? There seems to be a `2` missing from beginning of the expected output. I added that. If that was wrong, please remove it again.

Comment: You should highlight the distinct keyword  and value you want to match,  be it before or after. A simple regex, but if you introduce compound if's to it that would be ok as long as you state that. Otherwise your post is a witch hunt down the rabbit hole.

Answer (score 0):

The units are after the number, not before. So use two alternatives in the regexp. One alternative has `qty` as a lookbehind, the other has all the units as a lookahead.

```
(?i)(?:(?<=^qty\s)\d+|(?:\d+(?=\s?(?:qty|unit|pc|pcs|roll|rolls))))
```

A single spaces is required after `qty` when it's before the number, because lookbehinds have to be fixed length. The space is optional when the unit is after the number, so it will match `2pcs` and `500 pc`

Comment: regex101.com give me error pattern error

Comment: Thanks Works fine but only line matching problem is there any solution 
mbc 1015 qty 2 @ 20000

Comment: It's difficult to force one alternative or the other. Do you have to do it with regexp? You could do this as two separate regexp, so you can search for the preferred syntax first, then try the other if it doesn't match.